# I want to extract complete create table DDL query from file

Tags: unix, text-extraction

I have file which contains n number of CREATE table query, I want to extract some particular tables create table query in unix. 
For Example in below file I just want extract create table query of table xyz.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(
       a INTEGER NOT NULL,
       b INTEGER NOT NULL,
       c CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
  PARTITIONING KEY a USING HASHING 
  NOT LOGGED INITIALLY 
;
ALTER TABLE abc
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);

CREATE TABLE xyz(
       a INTEGER NOT NULL,
       b INTEGER NOT NULL,
       c CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
  PARTITIONING KEY a USING HASHING 
  NOT LOGGED INITIALLY 
;
ALTER TABLE xyz
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);


CREATE TABLE pqb(
       a INTEGER NOT NULL,
       b INTEGER NOT NULL,
       c CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
  PARTITIONING KEY a USING HASHING 
  NOT LOGGED INITIALLY 
;
ALTER TABLE pqb
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);
```

Comment: The file does not in same format.

Comment: format the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - you might like to see [How To Format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

> in below file I just want extract create table query of table xyz.

You could simply use `sed` to print the lines from `CREATE TABLE xyz` to `;`:

```
sed -n "/CREATE TABLE xyz/,/;/p" file
```

or with a parameter:

```
table=xyz
sed -n "/CREATE TABLE $table/,/;/p" file
```